# Native iOS app - Does the Firebase SDK have the capability to lock a user out of their account if they have failed 5 consecutive log-in attempts?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm creating the log-in page for a mobile app, will Firebase Auth allow me to cap log-in attempts at 5 before temporarily disabling the account?

I've been investigating the Firebase SDK to see if I can lock users out of their account if they have attempted 5 consecutive incorrect password entries.

I'm reviewing the errors available in the Firebase documentation and I see there are the following error codes:

```
FIRAuthErrorCodeWrongPassword, 
FIRAuthErrorCodeTooManyRequests,
FIRAuthErrorCodeUserDisabled
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to implement "account lockout" in your app, you can do the following:

1. Set the maximum number of allowed failed sign-in attempts. This can be done in the Firebase Console by going to the "Authentication" section and clicking on the "Sign-in method" tab. In the "Email/Password" section, you can set the "Maximum failed sign-in attempts" to the desired number (e.g. 5).
2. Handle the FIRAuthErrorCodeTooManyRequests error in your app's sign-in code. This error is returned by the Firebase Auth API when the maximum number of allowed failed sign-in attempts has been reached. When this error is returned, you can display a message to the user telling them that their account has been temporarily disabled and instructing them to contact customer support to reset their password.
3. Optionally, implement a mechanism to automatically reset the failed sign-in attempts counter after a certain amount of time. This can be done using the updateUser method of the Firebase Auth API and setting the reauthenticateBeforeUpdate parameter to true. This will require the user to re-enter their password before the failed sign-in attempts counter is reset, which can help prevent unauthorized access to the user's account.